# Return a limit of 2 records for each distinct column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assume I have a table that looks like this:

```
| Col A | Col B | Col C |
|-------|-------|-------|
|   1   |   A   |  54   |
|   1   |   A   |  56   |
|   1   |   B   |  55   |
|   1   |   B   |  51   |
|   1   |   C   |  36   |
|   1   |   C   |  23   |
|   1   |   D   |  62   |
|   1   |   D   |  11   |
|   2   |   B   |  88   |
|   2   |   B   |  17   |
|   2   |   C   |  56   |
|   2   |   C   |  86   |
|   2   |   D   |  47   |
|   2   |   D   |  29   |
```

What I want to do is grab the table to look like this:

```
| Col A | Col B | Col C |
|-------|-------|-------|
|   1   |   A   |  54   |
|   1   |   A   |  56   |
|   2   |   B   |  88   |
|   2   |   B   |  17   |
```

I'm pretty sure there is a way to do this, I just don't know how. First, I thought a `DISTINCT ON` selector would work, but that only returns one record for each value. In this case, I need two records for each value.

Comment: 2 records based on *what*?

Comment: Sorry. Just the first two records of each unique value in Col A.

Comment: so what 1st two records?  A, B? so order by colb the c?

Comment: The first two that you see for each unique value in Col A, So for `1`, you'd pull out the first two rows in the second table above. For `2`, you'd pull out the last two rows in the second table above.

Comment: Note ORDER in a database isn't guaranteed, so you must always be specific with an order by if you want records ina  specific order.  There's no reason why CC 56 and CC 86 may not appear before BB 88 and BB 17 unless you tell the system to sort first by colb!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use a window function to add a row number to each partition of data ordered by however you want and then select the anything with a row number less than 2.

```
With CTE AS (
SELECT colA, ColB, ColC, Row_Number() over (Partition by ColA ORDER By  ColB , ColC) RN
FROM Table)
Select * from cte where RN <=2
```

Since I didn't know what values of c you wanted, I choose to order by colC (ascending) so the lowest values of C would be returned for a given A+B combination.

Comment: Although it's not clear what OP's logic is, I think `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColA ORDER BY ColB)` is closer to their desired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
with
  grp as (select col_a from table group by col_a) -- It should be only index scan, not scanning the whole table
select * from grp join lateral (
  select * from table 
  where grp.col_a = table.col_a 
  order by <desired order here>
  limit 2) on true -- It also avoiding the full scan if properly indexes provided
```